# Regular Expression String Search Returns Group Not Match

Tags: regex

I'm a bit stuck with this regex, they make my head hurt lol

I'm trying to find a person's name between two known strings.

The beginning and end of the string are known but will have a few variations.

Here's the regex I'm working on, but I need it to return the first value, but it's returning a group.

So I know I'm on the right track.

```
(?<=Sales Call - [AB]: ).*?(?= and (Steve Test$|Randy Robbins$|Peter Pan$))
```

Here are some possible values I'm testing against:

String: Sales Call - A: Sally Warren and Steve Test

**Result**: Sally Warren

Sales Call - B: Ted Wilson and Randy Robbins

**Return**: Ted Wilson

Sales Call - A: Alicia Alton and Peter Pan

**Return**: Alicia Alton

So for clarification, I just need the middle string (the person's name) and nothing else but think my regex needs to be slightly tweaked.

Thanks!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are capturing something is because of the alternation at the end of the pattern:

```regex
(Steve Test$|Randy Robbins$|Peter Pan$)
```

You *could* make it a non capturing group:

```regex
(?:Steve Test$|Randy Robbins$|Peter Pan$)
```

However, I suggest using the following pattern instead:

```regex
(?<=Sales Call - [AB]: ).*?(?=\s+and \w+(?: \w+)*)
```

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/30YDth/1).